# Removing rogue formatting from CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have a MySQL database table I am exporting as a CSV file. One of the fields contains text that may be in large paragraphs. The problem is that the rows or breaking on some of the paragraphs. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kosPv.jpg

If I paste it into word with format characters on I see this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDN4o.jpg

The code I am using is this:

```
$rows = array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, "\t")) !== false) {
    $rows[] = $line;
}
```

I have tried both comma delimited and tab delimited, with all fields wrapped in double quotes.

How do I remove these newlines? What do those arrows mean in word (open office)?

I have tried replacing \t with '' with no luck.

Comment: those arrows are line-breaks, they are in the paragraph, I'm not seeing a problem. did you want that chunk of text split up?

Comment: No, I do not want it split up. It is splitting right in the middle of words. I show normal line breaks as new paragraph characters in that document, these seem to be different.

Comment: its like that in the database, so thats what needs to be fixed, its nothing to do with be turned in to a csv

Comment: The CSV files come to me already exported. I can't do anything about the database. I need to remove this formatting after it's in the CSV file unfortunetly.

Comment: you could remove all linebreaks, but i would expect some are wanted? how would you know which ones are splitting words?

Comment: The data in the database looks like this: (see below)

Comment: I just need to remove those line breaks that got added by the previous platform (I'm exporting data to a new system).

Comment: how can you tell which line breaks are wanted and which are not?